# What is the limit of $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n^4}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ k^2\int_{k}^{k+1}x\ln\big((x-k)(k+1-x)\big)dx\right)$

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits

As the topic how to find the limit of $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n^4}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ k^2\int_{k}^{k+1}x\ln\big((x-k)(k+1-x)\big)dx\right)\;.$$

Comment: The title and the body ask two different questions, let me answer the one in the body: decompose the log into the sum of two logs, transform every integral into an integral on $(0,1)$, perform the cancellations which appeared, use the fact that the sum of the $n$ first cubes is approximately $\frac14n^4$ and compute the integral of the log on $(0,1)$. The answer should be $-\frac12$.

Comment: i dont quite get how to manipulate it.

Comment: @Mathematics The integral is $$\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\int_{k}^{k+1}x\ln \left( \left( x-k\right) \left( k+1-x\right) \right) dx
\\
&=&\int_{k}^{k+1}x\ln \left( x-k\right) dx+\int_{k}^{k+1}x\ln \left(
k+1-x\right) dx \\
&=&\int_{0}^{1}\left( u+k\right) \ln u\,du+\int_{0}^{1}\left( k+1-u\right)
\ln u\,du \\
&=&\ldots  \\
&=&-k-\frac{1}{4}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: @Américo: Not $=-(2k+1)$? Maybe I am wrong, I did this too quickly and in my head, so...

Comment: @DidierPiau: Yes, you are right.  It is $(-k-1/4)+(-k-3/4)=-(2k+1)$

Comment: Correction:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\int_{k}^{k+1}x\ln \left( \left( x-k\right) \left( k+1-x\right) \right) dx
\\
&=&\int_{k}^{k+1}x\ln \left( x-k\right) dx+\int_{k}^{k+1}x\ln \left(
k+1-x\right) dx \\
&=&\int_{0}^{1}\left( u+k\right) \ln u\,du+\int_{0}^{1}\left( k+1-u\right)
\ln u\,du \\
&=&-k-\frac{1}{4}-k-\frac{3}{4} \\
&=&-2k-1
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: @Mathematics ... and the sum of squares and cubes of the first $n$ natural numbers is ([Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerSum.html) )
    $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{2}=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$
    and
    $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{3}=\frac{n^{2}(n+1)^{2}}{4}.$$

Comment: i get it,i thought i could solve it by mean of converting into a form of integration but obviously using the identities is the way to solve

Answer (score 2):

Put $I_k:=\int_k^{k+1}x\ln ((x-k)(k+1-x))dx$; making the substitution $t=x-k$ we have, following @Didier Piau-'s idea $$I_k=\int_0^1(t+k)\ln(t(1-t))dt=\int_0^1t\ln (t(1-t))dt+k\int_0^1\ln (t(1-t))dt.$$
Since $0\leq \frac 1{n^4}\sum_{k=1}^nk^2\leq \frac{n\cdot n^2}{n^4}$, the limit we are looking for is  $$l:=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac 1{n^4}\sum_{k=1}^nk^3\int_0^1(\ln t+\ln(1-t))dt.$$
Since $\sum_{k=1}^nk^3=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}4$, we have 
$$l=\frac 14\cdot 2\int_0^1\ln tdt=\frac 12\left([t\ln t]_0^1-\int_0^1t\frac 1tdt\right)=-\frac 12.$$

Comment: If you apply Stolz Cezaro to the original sequence you get exactly $\lim_n \frac{I_n}{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Two substitutions, first $x\mapsto x+k$ and then $x\mapsto1-x$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_k^{k+1}x\log\left((x-k)(k+1-x)\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^1(x+k)\log\left(x(1-x)\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^1(x+k)\left[\log\left(x\right)+\log\left(1-x\right)\right]\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^1(2k+1)\log(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-(2k+1)\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
This gives
$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n^4}\sum_{k=1}^nk^2\int_k^{k+1}x\log\left((x-k)(k+1-x)\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n^4}\sum_{k=1}^nk^2(2k+1)\\
&=-\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac kn\right)^2\left(2\frac kn+\frac1n\right)\frac1n\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
and $(2)$ is a Riemann sum for
$$
-\int_0^12x^3\,\mathrm{d}x=-\frac12\tag{3}
$$